# lucene search with wildcard is significantly slow

Tags: java, performance, optimization, lucene

I have a list of 1000 files (and growing twice as much a year) with text only and size ~8Mb per file, I'm trying to find the file name(s) given a (wildcard) expression.

Example, all files contain such data

> COD1004129641208240002709991455671866  4IT         /           HUF  4400QQQUF  3300QQQUF

and my search could be: "*9991455671866" which has a match to the line above.

Problem is (and maybe my expectations are too high) **it takes a bit over a minute to return the result.**

My doc indexing looks like this:

```
private Document getDocument(File file) throws IOException
{
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field(IndexProperties.FIELD_FILENAME, file.getName(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED)); 
    doc.add(new Field(IndexProperties.FIELD_CONTENT, reader));

    return doc;
}
```

the analyzer

```
        Directory fsDir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexFolder));
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);

        // build the writer
        IndexWriterConfig indexWriter = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(fsDir, indexWriter);
```

and the search by wildcard is:

```
public List<String> findFilenameByContent(String wildCardContent, String INDEX_FOLDER, String TICKETS_FOLDER) throws Exception
{   
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Term term = new Term(IndexProperties.FIELD_CONTENT, wildCardContent); //eg *9991455671866
    Query query = new WildcardQuery(term);

    //loop through docs
    Directory fsDir = FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEX_FOLDER));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.open(fsDir));
    ScoreDoc[] queryResults = searcher.search(query, 10).scoreDocs;  
    List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : queryResults) 
    {  
        Document doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);  
        strs.add(doc.get(IndexProperties.FIELD_FILENAME));
    }

    searcher.close();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("TOTAL SEARCH TIME: "+(end-start)/1000.0+ "secs");
    return strs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code.
If you only need to search, try:

```
IndexReader.open(fsDir,true);
```

It may improve your search time.

[This suggestions may help.](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed)